# Why can't I redirect url's with "index.html" in it to a php file?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm stuck in a big problem, but let me start with one part of it.

I am wodering why this works:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html $1 [R=301,L]
```

while this doesn't:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) main.redirect.php [QSA,L]
```

And this one doesn't work as well:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html main.redirect.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Any ideas?

I'm using this as part of a main problem, where the customer wants me to only do one redirect for either one or all of the following conditions

- www is missing (put it in front)
- index.html is at the end (remove it)
- CAPS are present (convert to lowercase)

To achieve this, I created a php file which does all that in one go, and I need to call that on either one of the conditions above (the php file will do the redirect then):

```
<?php
$sURL = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo '$sURL = ' . $sURL . '<br />';
$sURL = strtolower($sURL);
if (substr($sURL, 0, 4) != 'www.') {
    $sURL = 'www.' . $sURL;
}
if (substr($sURL, -10) == 'index.html') {
    $sURL = substr($sURL, 0, -10);
}
echo 'Location: http://' . $sURL;
#header('Location: http://' . $sURL, true, 301);
?>
```

(the echo lines are for testing purposes, they will be removed and the header() command activated later)

In the .htaccess file, I now have the following (right after "RewriteEngine On" and "Options +FollowSymlinks":

```
    # 2014-07-16 RM: Exclude these files from rewriting
    RewriteRule \.(js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|pdf)$ - [NC,QSA,L]

    # 2014-07-16 RM: Check if the url starts with www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) main.redirect.php [QSA,L]

    # 2014-07-16 RM: Check if the url ends with index.html
#    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} ^(.*)index\.html$ [NC]
#    RewriteRule ^(.*) main.redirect.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html main.redirect.php [NC,QSA,L]

    # 2014-07-16 RM: Check if the url contains upper-case characters
#    RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]
#    RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:FALSE,S=1]
#    RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
#    RewriteRule ^(.*) main.redirect.php [QSA,L]
```

Any help is gladly appreciated!

Kind regards

René

EDIT:

I stripped the .htaccess part down to a few lines, but even in this case only the www-check works as expected:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/index\.html$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(.*) main.redirect.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, however the first thing I spotted was that in your RewriteRule lines which are like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) main.redirect.php [QSA,L]
```

You should try adding a slash before main.redirect.php as that part of the redirect rule should be a URL, so it would become:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /main.redirect.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, but as I stated above, it works for the www-check part, so this can't be the problem.